# Work with ASP.NET SignalR in React Native

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, react-native, asp.net-core, signalr

Actually, I wanna to build chat app with `ASP.NET` and `SignalR` in `React Native`.

My backend `API` comes from `ASP.NET` Without change server from ASP.NET to ASP.NET Core, is it possible to work with `SignalR` in `React Native`?

I have tested `@aspnet/signalr` and it is not compatible with `ASP.NET` and also I tested [signalr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/signalr)  and it requires `jQuery` on `React Native`!! (I think it is just for `ReactJS`, not `React-native`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading `SignalR` documentation and some try and error I found this package useful for my project [react-native-signalr](https://github.com/olofd/react-native-signalr). just remember that url should add like this:

```
const connection = signalr.hubConnection(YOUR_SERVER_URL, {
      qs: {
        access_token:
        'YOUR_API_TOKEN',
      },
    });
```

Comment: This library seems to be outdated by now, use the official [@microsoft/signalr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/signalr) or [react-signalr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-signalr)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this on React or React Native.

Use the official SignalR package [@microsoft/signalr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/signalr)

```
const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("https://LinkOfTheEndPoin", {
      accessTokenFactory: () => 'JWT_TOKEN_HERE',
    })
    .withAutomaticReconnect()
    .configureLogging(LogLevel.Information)
    .build();

  connection.start();
```

"LogLevel.Information" will help you to understand what's going on the background!

Comment: This will only work for it server is ASP NET CORE